# How to convert string into numbers in python

Tags: python, string, numbers

I see an interesting python exercise in codewars.it is about convert strings to numbers.I want some suggestions or guidance to solve this python exercise.Thank you

this is the exercise:In this kata we want to convert a string into an integer. The strings simply represent the numbers in words.
Examples:
"one"1

and this is my code:

```
def parse_int(string):
    dict_of_numbers={ "zero":0, "one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5, "six":6, "seven":7, "eight":8, "nine":9,"ten":10, "eleven":11, "twelve":12, "thirteen":13, "fourteen":14, "fifteen":15, "sixteen":16, "seventeen":17, "eighteen":18, "nineteen":19, "twenty":20, "thirty":30, "forty":40, "fifty":50, "sixty":60, "seventy":70, "eighty":80, "ninety":90,"thousand":1000,"hundred":100}

    string=string.replace(' ','-')
    numbers=string.split('-')
    created_number=0
    for number in numbers:
        for key,value in dict_of_numbers.items():
            if number==key:
                created_number+=value
    return created_number
```

Comment: what do you need help with? it works for me

Comment: it doesn't work for big numebrs.for example seven hundred eighty-three thousand nine hundred and nineteen

Comment: Yep. IT failed on `one hundred`.

Comment: You are assuming the spoken numbers are summed up. However in some situations they are multiplied. For example `seven hundred`. You must multiply the number before the hundred with 100.

Comment: May have a look at how the developer of `word2number` solved this, as the translation from spoken numbers to integers is not that easy due to the issue @MSH mentioned: [GitHub](https://github.com/akshaynagpal/w2n/blob/master/word2number/w2n.py)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution and I did not test it for large collection of numbers but it may give you some ideas:

1. Spoken numbers sometimes are summed sometimes are multiplied.
2. Some times people put an `and` between numbers. Like: `thirty seven thousand and twenty one`
3. Don't use `[]` to get value from your dictionary. Use `get` method. So if there is not data corresponding to the number you have control over the return.
4. use str's `.lower()` to lower the letters in the string to avoid upper case, lower case problem

The code I wrote would look like:

```
def parse_int(string):
    dict_of_numbers = {"zero": 0, "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "four": 4, "five": 5, "six": 6, "seven": 7,
                       "eight": 8, "nine": 9, "ten": 10, "eleven": 11, "twelve": 12, "thirteen": 13, "fourteen": 14,
                       "fifteen": 15, "sixteen": 16, "seventeen": 17, "eighteen": 18, "nineteen": 19, "twenty": 20,
                       "thirty": 30, "forty": 40, "fifty": 50, "sixty": 60, "seventy": 70, "eighty": 80, "ninety": 90,
                       "thousand": 1000, "hundred": 100}

    string = string.replace(" and ", " ")
    the_number = 0
    for each in string.lower().split():
        if each in ["hundred", "thousand"]:
            the_number *= dict_of_numbers.get(each, 1)
        else:
            the_number += dict_of_numbers.get(each, 0)


    return the_number


print(parse_int("thirty seven thousand and twenty two")) # 37022
```